# Post JSON file and assign to variable with new cUrl --json option (2022)

Tags: curl, gitlab

I recently saw an article (https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/02/02/curl-dash-dash-json/) regarding a new `--json` option in `cUrl` (February 2022). I want to try to store a `JSON` file in a variable and send it to a pipeline using this option.

Usually, to send a file to a pipeline I would do something similar to this:

```
curl -i -X POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<my-id>/trigger/pipeline?token=<my-token>&ref=<my-branch>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@path\to\file.json"
```

So I the equivalent with the `--json` option would be:

```
curl -i -X POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<my-id>/trigger/pipeline?token=<my-token>&ref=<my-branch>" -json "@path\to\file.json"
```

The two first commands work.

I tried something different to not only send the file to the pipeline but also assign it to a variable so that I could call the content of the file with '$var_name' whenever I needed it.

Usually if the variable is a string I just do this:

```
curl --request POST --form token=<my-token> --form ref=<my-branch> --form "variables[var_name]=string" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<my-id>/trigger/pipeline"
```

So I tried the following to retrieve the content of a file instead:

```
curl --request POST --form token=<my-token> --form ref=<my-branch> --form "variables[var_name]=@path\to\file.json" -json "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<my-id>/trigger/pipeline"
```

However, the pipeline did not trigger in that case. I did not get any error at all, but I cannot spot any reaction from the pipeline. How would I assign the file to a variable using the new `--json` option?

Comment: Can you describe the contents of your file and the expected resulting variables?

Comment: Drop `-X POST` from both command lines, and in the second one you only use a single dash (`-`) instead of `--json`

Comment: @sytech It is an open question, the input would be just a random dictionnary stored in a JSON file.

Comment: @LoïcPoncin I'm not sure I understand the problem. Have you tried this? What errors are you getting if any?

Comment: @sytech Sorry, the commands standlone work, but I was wondering more about the variable part. I updated the question, my bad.